# Make text appear immediately but fade out gradually using modern CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, opacity, fade

I'm OK at JavaScript but bad at CSS and completely new to transitions and fades.

Examples that I've looked at that were simple enough to understand at a glance did fading both in and out.

Examples that did closer to what I want didn't seem as simple to grok so quickly, but then again those questions didn't ask specifically and only what I'm asking here.

I'll set the text and initiate the fading with JS but is there a way where that's all I have to do, ignoring when the fade is finished?

I've tried just removing the transition style and setting the opacity, then adding the text and putting the transition style back in and setting the new opacity, which doesn't work:

```
span.style.transition = '';
span.style.opacity = '1';
span.textContent = 'fading message';
span.style.transition = 'opacity 1s';
span.style.opacity = '0';
```

Comment: Do you have a CSS file that also adds a transition on your `span`?  If so, doing `span.style.transition = '';` will not remove the transition since it is changing the DOM attribute `style=""`.  You could try `span.style.transition = 'none';`

Comment: Also, your code seems to do the revers of your question?  `opacity:0;` means transparent, fading to opaque (`opacity:1;`), but your question says "appear immediately but fade out"

Comment: No. So far I've got very little CSS in my prototype at all, this is one of the first bits of CSS I'm putting into it. I trued tried `'none'` but the message now fades in once (rather than out) and stays fully opaque, irregardless of subsequent calls to this bit of code.

Comment: OK, so if you invert lines 2 and 5 of your javascript, I think you should have what you want?

Comment: No I tried that, fixed that part of the code, and upvoted your comment pointing out that particular error. But it's not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I believe this is the solution you are looking for:

```js
document.getElementById('btn_click').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var span = document.getElementById('fader');
    
    span.style.transition = 'none';
    span.style.opacity = '1';
    span.textContent = 'fading message';
    
    /* This line seems to 'reset' the element so that the transition can be run again. */
    void span.offsetWidth;
    
    span.style.transition = 'opacity 1s';
    span.style.opacity = '0';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="fader"></span><br/>
  <button id="btn_click">Click to fade</button>
</div>
```

Note especially the line `void span.offsetWidth;`, which seems to do some sort of a reset.  I found this out [here](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/#article-header-id-0).

Comment: Wow thanks! I'm surprised it requires some kind of trick. I assumed I was missing something very obvious at the beginner level!